# Help With Find Missing Files

Tags: texturing, image, uv-image-editor, blend-files, file-browser

I have a model that's portraying the purple material to show something is missing. So I thought "OK, whatever I'll just hit the 'Find Missing Files' Button," but for some reason even though I select the images individually for the model the images are still saying that they can't be found. Any ideas?

Here is a more in-depth look at the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHvf14zPUCw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try put the images inside a folder and then find your file, make sure you didnt rename them, then open the folder inside blender menu and click find missing files

Comment: I updated my answer